# VBA: Word saves .docx file as a .doc file, how to save as a docx?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, docx, doc

In Excel I have a few macro's that work perfect. What I do with these macro's is open a Word document (.docx), fill the bookmarks with data from the Excel file, save the separate Word documents with some data in the filename, in a specified folder. No big deal (anymore).

The thing is that the input files are .docx files. The output files are .doc (Word 97-2003 compatible).

How to save the output documents as .docx files?
The part of my VBA that is responsible for the saving is this:

```
wordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    WordDoc.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "GoNoGo\GoNoGo BOL " & strVoornaam & Space(1) & strAchternaam, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
    WordDoc.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdsaveformat-enumeration-word  Are you using late binding?  If Yes you need to define the file format constant

Comment: Crap, I missed that. Thanks a lot. It's solved now.

I have no clue about late binding or not. It's my first VBA project, with a lot of help from people on the internet.

Comment: If you're referencing the Word object model / type library, Word constants are defined and you should declare Word objects using the types defined in the Word object model. If you're *not* referencing the Word type library, Word constants are NOT defined and you should use their underlying value, and you need to late-bind the object types, i.e. declare them `As Object`, which makes VBA resolve the actual types at run-time (hence, *late* binding, vs compile-time / *early* binding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this:

```
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
```

You are telling VBA to save as .doc.

It should be:

```
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

Check out the possible files formats here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/word-vba/articles/wdsaveformat-enumeration-word

Comment: This is incorrect. The default format is not necessarily docx. That's the installation default, but that can be changed by the user or by the network admin.

Comment: Not incorrect, but inaccurate. This should normaly work and I did provide the link with all options.

Comment: I changed it to FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, after reading the link @Tim Williams gave above, the same link Franksta gave. In there you can read the final extension of the document that's created with a VBA. For me the FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault would do, it's creating nice .docx files with no further compatibility issues.

Comment: Great to hear that it works. Would you then mark the question as answered?